# T-SQL Dynamic Query

Tags: sql-server

My question is how can I improve my query string in a smart way?

I want to use parameters query data from DB when the parameter is null it will be eliminated.

My query string likes below:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spQueryDataFromCPREFROM]
@CompanyName varchar(50),
@TestDDL varchar(20),
@TesterName varchar(50),
@DatepickerForTestDate datetime,
@ApplyDate datetime,
@TestTypeDDL varchar(1),
@QueryString nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    if @CompanyName is not null 
       and @TestDDL is not null 
       and @TesterName is not null
       and @DatepickerForTestDate is not null
       and @ApplyDate is not null
       and @TestTypeDDL is not null
       and @QueryString is not null 
       begin 
            select @QueryString = 'select * from [dbo].[CPREFROM] as CF where CF.[UNIT_TID] ='+ @CompanyName 
                                    +'and CF.[ELIGIBLE_RATING] ='+ @TestDDL 
                                    +'and CF.[Name] =' + @TesterName
                                    +'and CF.[CHECKDATE] ='+ @DatepickerForTestDate
                                    +'and CF.[APPLYDATE] =' + @ApplyDate
                                    +'and CF.[A_S] =' + @TestTypeDDL
       end
     else if @CompanyName is null 
            and @TestDDL is not null 
            and @TesterName is not null
            and @DatepickerForTestDate is not null
            and @ApplyDate is not null
            and @TestTypeDDL is not null
            and @QueryString is not null 
            begin 
                select @QueryString = 'select * from [dbo].[CPREFROM] as CF where CF.[ELIGIBLE_RATING] ='+ @TestDDL 
                                    +'and CF.[Name] =' + @TesterName
                                    +'and CF.[CHECKDATE] ='+ @DatepickerForTestDate
                                    +'and CF.[APPLYDATE] =' + @ApplyDate
                                    +'and CF.[A_S] =' + @TestTypeDDL
            end
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can below help for you ?
For example:

"CF.[UNIT_TID]=CF.[UNIT_TID]" same as 1=1

```
        select @QueryString = 'select * from [dbo].[CPREFROM] as CF where CF.[UNIT_TID] ='+ ISNULL(@CompanyName,'CF.[UNIT_TID]') 
                                +'and CF.[ELIGIBLE_RATING] ='+ ISNULL(@TestDDL,'CF.[ELIGIBLE_RATING]')
                                +'and CF.[Name] =' + ISNULL(@TesterName,'CF.[Name]')
                                +'and CF.[CHECKDATE] ='+ ISNULL(@DatepickerForTestDate,'CF.[CHECKDATE]')
                                +'and CF.[APPLYDATE] =' + ISNULL(@ApplyDate,'CF.[APPLYDATE]')
                                +'and CF.[A_S] =' + ISNULL(@TestTypeDDL,'CF.[A_S]')
```

But if the value possible is null you need use ISNULL to process the value
because the result of "NULL=NULL" is not true.

sample:

```
+'and ISNULL(CF.[Name],'''') =' + ISNULL(@TesterName,'ISNULL(CF.[Name],'''')')
```