# SSRS 2008 Drill through parameter filtering >= not working

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, drillthrough

I have a main summary report which has count and a drill through report showing the detail which has a parameter where the count from main report is passed to drill through. But I want to see the drill through report which has count greater than or equal to 2. If I give >=2 in the parameter section where you specify the drill through report name and parameters, nothing is getting selected in drill through when I run the main report. If I specify one value, it is running fine but if I give >=2, the main report is running but no value is selected in parameter that too if I specify the parameter as text. If I define the parameter as integer, it's giving data mismatch error and the report is not running at all. If I define as text, the main report is running but no parameter is selected. Could some one please advise. Thanks for your time

From the main report, I want to see the drill through report which has count>=2 . How do I pass >=2 to the count parameter in drill through report. I have only one requirement- to pass >=2 as a parameter. How do I achieve this.

Comment: You can't pass a filter in like that. You can pass in the count as a parameter (just the numeric value) and then use that in your filter expression but I don;t fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Please edit your question and show details of you main and subreports, a sample of data and expected output.

Comment: Hi Alan, I have edited my original question. I am passing integers only. I just want to know how to pass >=2 to the count parameter. The problem is all with giving >=. Please advise how to achieve this.Thanks

Comment: I still don't u derstand. Remember we cannot see your code or report design. Please show report design and sample data

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is expecting a single number. 
If you want it to equal the parameter sometimes and be greater than others, you would need to create a second parameter and then have your detail report deal with it with an OR for the filter. `

In the Query (assuming CNT is the count field):

```
WHERE (CNT = @CNT AND @OPERATOR = '=') OR (CNT >= @CNT AND @OPERATOR = '>=')
```

For a dataset filter, the expression would be something like:

```
=IIF((Fields!CNT.Value = Parameters!CNT.Value AND Parameters!OPERATOR.Value = "=") OR (Fields!CNT.Value >= Parameters!CNT.Value AND Parameters!OPERATOR.Value = ">="), 1, 0)
```

Set the Type to INTEGER, the **Operator** to = and the **Value** to 1.

The expression checks to see if the record is either equal to the count when = is selected or >= the count when >= is selected and gives that record a value of 1 otherwise it's 0. Then the filter checks for ones that are equal to 1.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. From the main report, I want to see the drill through report which has count>=2 . How do I pass >=2 to the count parameter in drill through report. I have only one requirement- to pass >=2 as a parameter..  Is there any easy way to do it.

Comment: If you really wanted to pass **>=2** as a single parameter, you would have to pass it as a string and then use the string to create your query as a string variable (@SQL) and then execute it with EXEC @SQL. But when you want just 2, you would need to enter **=2**. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901891/t-sql-dynamic-query

Comment: Thanks Hannover Fist. I figured it out.